# Remove key from complicated list of dictionary without knowing name of key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this complicated list of dictionaries in python.

```
[{'2019': {'LastDate': '2019-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},
 {'2018': {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},
 {'2017': {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}}                       
]
```

I want to remove the ALL the keys `2019`, `2018`, `2017` without knowing the names of these keys. The end result should look something like this;

```
[{'LastDate': '2019-12-31',
    'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
    'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},  
 {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
    'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
    'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},
 {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
    'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
    'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},                      
]
```

The problem gets complicated when the name of the keys are unknown.
I am using python 3.7.

Comment: What is the criterion of which keys will be removed?

Comment: @ParthS007, I want all the keys to be removed. No criterion.

Comment: So, in essence you want to only keep a list of the `values` and ditch the `keys`? why not just create a list from the values?

Comment: @Dror Av., any hint on how to do that? thanks. Stuck at this problem for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate through the available list and append the key's value to another list and another list will be your expected result.

You can create a list of values like this:

```
original_list = [
    {
        "2019": {
            "LastDate": "2019-12-31",
            "Header": {
                "HeaderStd": None,
                "TimeType": {"#text": "Months", "@Code": "M"},
            },
            "Item": [
                {"#text": "299021.000000", "@Code": "XXX"},
                {"#text": "299021.000000", "@Code": "YYY"},
                {"#text": "10.110920", "@Code": "ZZZ"},
            ],
        }
    },
]

result = [ ]

for element in original_list:
      for value in element.values():
          result.append(value)
print(result)
```

**Result:**

```
[
    {
        "LastDate": "2019-12-31",
        "Header": {"HeaderStd": None, "TimeType": {"#text": "Months", "@Code": "M"}},
        "Item": [
            {"#text": "299021.000000", "@Code": "XXX"},
            {"#text": "299021.000000", "@Code": "YYY"},
            {"#text": "10.110920", "@Code": "ZZZ"},
        ],
    }
]
```

Comment: I tested the edited answers. Don't seem to work the same as the original one where you use `for dictionary in `. When I tried to `pprint` the output, it looks funny compared to original one.

Comment: let me check again

Comment: You may want to revert back to the original answer which I tested to be working.

Comment: @user3848207 can you check again. Added the output as well.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use iterable/tuple unpacking (`*`) on `d.values()` to achieve your desired result, because `d.values()` will yield a `dict_values` object, containing the nested dictionaries, and not just the dictionaries themselves.

```
l = [{'2019': {'LastDate': '2019-12-31',
       'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                    'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
       'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                    {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                    {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},
 {'2018': {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},
 {'2017': {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}}                       
]



result = []
for d in l:
  result.append(*d.values())

print(result)
```

Output:

```
 [{'2019': {'LastDate': '2019-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},
 {'2018': {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}},
 {'2017': {'LastDate': '2018-12-31',
           'Header': {'HeaderStd': None,
                        'TimeType': {'#text': 'Months', '@Code': 'M'}},
           'Item': [{'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'XXX'},
                        {'#text': '299021.000000', '@Code': 'YYY'},
                        {'#text': '10.110920', '@Code': 'ZZZ'}]}}                       
]
```